# How to start applications in certain places ONLY during autostart

Tags: openbox

As title explains I wish to start programs in a specific place but only at the startup of my computer. If a program is opened afterwords I would like it to launch normally in my current desktop.

Comment: A specific place? Where? Australia? Europe? or are we talking more specific? like Milano? Genevra?

Comment: Position on screen

Comment: Having things run at start up is easy just write a unit file and enable it https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_unit_files, as for a certain position on the screen, you need to give us more information. What "programs" are you running, where on the screen? Why do they need to be in a specific location?

Comment: Running Visual studio Code on second desktop. Running a terminator terminal on desktop 1 and 2. I like to have these things start instantly where I want them.

Comment: Write a script that opens each process in the background, and you will likely want to use the `DISPLAY` environment variable